# How to Group by with Count()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
[OrderNo]   [OrderStatus]
PO-01       Received
PO-01       Pending
PO-01       Received
PO-02       Pending
PO-02       Pending
PO-03       Received
PO-03       Received
```

In a Table a have two Column OrderNo and OrderStatus
I want a Result like.

```
[OrderNo]   [OrderStatus]
PO-01       Partially Received
PO-02       Pending
PO-03       Received in Full
```

If All Rows of Particular [OrderNo] is Received then Make its Status 'Received in Full' and if Not make its status 'Partially received' and if Every Row is in Pending Status make its Status 'Pending'

Comment: You're also doing something with the statuses there: if not part of the question please make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with Orders 
as (
  select distinct OrderNo from TableOrders
)

select OrderNo,

       case when not exists (select * 
                             from TableOrders 
                             where TableOrders.OrderNo = Orders.OrderNo and
                                   OrderStatus = 'Received') 
                 then 'Pending'

             when exists (select *
                          from TableOrders 
                          where TableOrders.OrderNo = Orders.OrderNo and
                                OrderStatus = 'Pending') 
                  then 'Partially Received'

              else 'Received in Full' 
       end as Status              

from Orders
```

Comment: Good answer. You have missed the `end` at the end of your case statement `else 'Received in Full' end as Satus `

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only two status in OrderStatus

```
declare @sales1 table
(orderNo nvarchar(10), orderStatus nvarchar(20) )
insert into      @sales1

select 'PO-01',       'Received'
union all select 'PO-01',       'Pending'
union all select 'PO-01',       'Received'
union all select 'PO-02',       'Pending'
union all select 'PO-02',       'Pending'
union all select 'PO-03',       'Received'
union all select 'PO-03',       'Received'



 SELECT orderNo
        ,CASE WHEN count(*) = sum(orderStatus)
                AND sum(orderStatus) > 0 THEN 'Pending' WHEN sum(orderStatus) > 0 THEN 'Partially Received' WHEN sum(orderStatus) = 0 THEN 'Received in full' END AS ststus
    FROM (
        SELECT orderNo
            ,CASE WHEN orderStatus = 'Received' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS orderStatus
        FROM @sales1
        ) t
    GROUP BY orderNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using JOIN:

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE 
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),OrderNo VARCHAR(20),OrderStatus VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('PO-01','Received'),
    ('PO-01','Pending'),
    ('PO-01','Received'),
    ('PO-02','Pending'),
    ('PO-02','Pending'),
    ('PO-03','Received'),
    ('PO-03','Received')


    SELECT DISTINCT A.OrderNo,
    CASE WHEN  A.OrderStatus = 'Partially Received' THEN A.OrderStatus
    ELSE B.OrderStatus END AS [OrderStatus] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        OrderNo,
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT OrderStatus) > 1 THEN 'Partially Received' 
            ELSE 'Status' END AS [OrderStatus] 

        FROM @t 
        GROUP BY OrderNo
    ) A 
    INNER JOIN @t B ON A.OrderNo = B.OrderNo
```